# bitmap image on remote views disappear after reboot

Tags: android

I have a question about android app widget icon image... 
I am currently working on a side project and it uses app widget for one of the functionality.. I have successfully set up the app widget's preview image and remote views for the actual icon to click on on the home screen by implementing WidgetConfig activity and xml... making new widget place an icon with user profile image and user name on home screen so that the user can interact with it.. all works fine but after rebooting the device, the image is gone and clicking event does not work anymore... any idea what to do?? It seems like rebooting the device resets all configuration that I have specified...